# Unable to remove Python 3.7 from macOS

Tags: macos, python

I’m trying to remove Python 3 from my laptop but just can’t seem to be able to do so.

Below is the output for `ls -ls /usr/bin/python*`:

```
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
16 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31456 Oct 23 18:33 /usr/bin/python3
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Oct 12 12:33 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

I tried the solution given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/3422813), but even that did not work for me.

I also tried doing `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python3` after disabling SIP,
but I get an error saying

```
rm: /usr/bin/python3: Read-only file system
```

I want to remove this and do a clean install via Homebrew or pyenv.

Comment: What is your real goal here? Why do you want to remove the system Python from macOS? As the top of that answer clearly states in bold, “**Do not attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in `/System/Library` and `/usr/bin`, as this may break your whole operating system.**” You do state, “I want to remove this and do a clean install via homebrew or pyenv.” but homebrew or pyenv do not need to have the core OS version of Python remove to work. You can install both side by side.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not trying to remove the system Python from macOS. From what I understand /user/bin/python3 is not the apple-supplied system python. I don't understand where ```16 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31456 Oct 23 18:33 /usr/bin/python3``` came from and wanted to remove it.

Comment: Which version of macOS is that? Shouldn't Catalina have `python3`? --> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes

Comment: @DarshanDagly I generally feel that what you are trying to do is more forceful and destructive than necessary. I would recommend just installing the Hombrew version of Python without worries and just make sure you PATH in the Terminal (Bash or Zsh) has the Homebrew paths before the default system paths as it should be when you use Homebrew.

Comment: Also, regarding the read-only file system read up on how macOS (beginning with Catalina) has a read-only filesystem for core OS functions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650

Comment: Why are you trying to remove Python 3, when the Python 2.7 EOL is literally a month a way?

Answer (score 12):

macOS Catalina 10.15.x contains Python 2.7.x and Python 3.7.x built into the OS, for the purposes of parts of the OS that use Python. If these versions/installations meet your needs, you can use them, but if they don't meet your needs, you shouldn't remove them, as they're needed by the OS. Removing them or replacing them with different versions may create incompatibilities that break your OS, sometimes in frustratingly subtle ways.

If the built-in system versions don't meet your needs, you should leave them in-place and install your own versions somewhere else, like `/usr/local/bin` (as Homebrew will help you do), and then put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` (or do something else to ensure that you're always invoking your own version/install of Python instead of the system Python).

Removing or modifying the OS's Python install without knowing exactly how the system uses its own Python install, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Not to mention Python 2.7 EOL occurs in a month.